# isolating public network and a staff network

Tags: networking

my small office has two networks, each of them are connected to a switch, those switches then connect to a central switch which then connect to a router ADSL capable.

The router is connected to the WAN which provides the internet connection to all devices on this network.

I plan to have these two networks which is connected to the same central switch be **isolated** from each other since the other network is a public network. We don't want the traffic to be mixed up.

Since both network shares the same internet connection. how can I isolate these two networks?

I appreciate any advice on this.

Comment: From [Tim_Stewart](https://superuser.com/users/864102/tim-stewart): Cisco routers and switches are VLAN capable. If your router is newer then 2004 most likely it supports it. What kind of switches do you have? Cisco small business switches are relatively cheap and support what you are trying to do. Are these managed switches? I.e do they have console access? If they don't you should probably replace them anyway. Model numbers would help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your IP addresses are well defined you may not have any collisions, but a good approach may be using **subnet** masks and **ACLs** on the router so that traffic from one subnet has no access to traffic of the other subnet. I only know how to configure ACLs on cisco routers so if it's another brand I can't help you very much. But subnetting can be used on (almost) any router, you just have to set up your network like this:

```
Subnet A

Gateway: 192.168.1.127 and subnet 255.255.255.128
```

Only IPs in the range of .1 up to .127 will have direct access between them.

```
Subnet B

Gateway: 192.168.1.254 and subnet 255.255.255.128
```

Likewise, only IPs in the range of .129 up to .254 will have direct access between them.

If any computer inside Subnet A wants to communicate with any computer inside the Subnet B they'll have to pass through the router, and that's where ACLs come into action, they may block or let access for certain IPs or block any IP of a certain subnet completely.

Of course the swicthes must connect to different ethernet ports of the router (each one is the respective gateway for each subnet, the router must let you specify an IP address for each port), otherwise you must implement VLANs and use a trunk port to connect.

I'm a little too rusty now regarding networking but I hope this helps you.

Good luck.

Comment: great advice, I will look more into ACL, I'm using CISCO 857-K9 router. I want to ask, why IPs in the range of .129 up to .254 have direct access between them?

Comment: For direct access I mean that they don't have to pass through the router to communicate since they're in the same subnet and they're under the same broadcast domain.

Comment: Because they are in the smell subnet range. It's the nature of the addressing system.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood, thanks.do you have any tutorials I can use for setting ACL for this scenario?

Comment: It's just a basic ACL configuration where all communication coming from a certain subnet is blocked. Any tutorial or basic ACL guide would serve you well. And I'm on my phone right now.

Comment: You're welcome and good luck.

Comment: @arielnmz i'm little confused about something, setting up two different subnets, do I set it on the central switch or the router?

Comment: You must have to specify an address inside the range as well as the mask on every host you want to be inside subnet a or b and the router's ports must have an IP inside the respective range too. Like this: if you want port fa0/1 to be the gateway of subnet A you must set it's IP to 192.168.1.127 and its mask to /25 or 255.255.255.128 (the hosts must have the same mask), so every computer with an IP of .126 down to .1 could use this port as the gateway (of course the switch that connects them should be connected to that port). And the same for subnet B.

Comment: @arielnmz, oh I understand now, that clear things up. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using VLANs. Can your router do this? It can create two or more logical networks that are completely separated from one another. The two VLANs should have different subnets so one network cannot connect to devices on the other.

An example device that can do VLANs at a reasonable price (it can do wifi and ethernet VLANs) is a DrayTek Vigor 2920n. For a small business this is OK.

If your have an Active Directory (Windows Server) on your network then this should be used to provide DHCP to your office network. Your guest network should be separated from this network completely.

Comment: is there any cons of using VLANs? will it require to have a higher end router?